# Play app not responding in production

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I'm using play framework 2.2.1 in production for rest api. After 4-5 hours work app just freeze... and not responding. After restart same things.

**jstack** return `target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded`

I'm also use MongoDb like database and RabitMQ.

[Edit]

Linux ubuntu 12.04, jdk1.7.0 (not open openjdk);

Nginx as proxy 80 to 9000

`kill -3` - return nothing

Nginx error.log

```
*39806 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client
```

Comment: Can you get a heap dump from it? Or a thread dump by running kill -3 on it?

Comment: @JamesRoper I'll do it when this will happen next time

Comment: What's the software stack? Linux (which distor)? JDK version?

Comment: @BahmanM. Linux ubuntu 12.04, jdk1.7.0 (not open openjdk)

Comment: Any clue in Play logs and Linux logs? Is there a web server (e.g. nginx) in front of Play as a proxy? Check its logs too.

Comment: @BahmanM. Nginx as proxy logs: "upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client"

Comment: Before checking the proxy try to access your Play application and check if it is up.